# Render custom XAML inside cells of a particular column in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid and I would like to have my first column's cells all render some custom XAML.

Currently I have just the grid:

```
        <DataGrid CanUserSortColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" HeadersVisibility="Column" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Foo}" Header="Foo"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Bar}" Header="Bar"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

For starters, I would like to be able to add some specific WPF control/XAML into the first column's cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with a `CellTemplate`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Foo">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Foo}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```